# Symbol not found - Java

Tags: java, gwt, smartgwt, olap4j

I'm using Olap4j to connect to the OLAP server in GWT. However, when I try to iterate through rows and columns I get a 'Symbol not found' error during compilation.

My code

```
for (Position axis_0 : cellSet.getAxes().get(Axis.COLUMNS.axisOrdinal()).getPositions()) {
            List<Member> mem0 = axis_0.getMembers();
            for (Position axis_1 : cellSet.getAxes().get(Axis.ROWS.axisOrdinal()).getPositions()) {
                List<Member> mem1 = axis_1.getMembers();
                Cell currentCell = cellSet.getCell(axis_0, axis_1);
                data = new HashMap();
                for (int i = 0; i < mem0.size(); i++) {
                    data.put(mem0.get(i).getDimension().getName().replaceAll(" ", ""), mem0.get(i).getUniqueName());
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < mem1.size(); i++) {
                    data.put(mem1.get(i).getDimension().getName().replaceAll(" ", ""), mem1.get(i).getUniqueName());
                }
                data.put("value", Float.parseFloat((currentCell.getValue()==null)?"0":currentCell.getValue().toString()));
                data.put("cellID", count);
                data.put("Scenarios", scenario);
                collection.add(data);
                count+=1;
            }
        }
```

The error

[image: Error message]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the code validated by restructuring it like this:

```
    CellSetAxis columnAxis = (CellSetAxis) cellSet.getAxes().get(Axis.COLUMNS.axisOrdinal());
    CellSetAxis rowAxis = (CellSetAxis) cellSet.getAxes().get(Axis.ROWS.axisOrdinal());
    List<Position> colPositions = columnAxis.getPositions();
    List<Position> rowPositions = rowAxis.getPositions();

    for (Position axis_0 : colPositions) {
        List<Member> mem0 = axis_0.getMembers();
        for (Position axis_1 : rowPositions) {
            List<Member> mem1 = axis_1.getMembers();
            Cell currentCell = cellSet.getCell(axis_0, axis_1);
            data = new HashMap();
            for (int i = 0; i < mem0.size(); i++) {
                data.put(mem0.get(i).getDimension().getName().replaceAll(" ", ""), mem0.get(i).getUniqueName());
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < mem1.size(); i++) {
                data.put(mem1.get(i).getDimension().getName().replaceAll(" ", ""), mem1.get(i).getUniqueName());
            }
            data.put("value", Float.parseFloat((currentCell.getValue()==null)?"0":currentCell.getValue().toString()));
            data.put("cellID", count);
            data.put("Scenarios", scenario);
            collection.add(data);
            count+=1;
        }
    }
```